# Using WPF Triggers to Change Properties of Named Elements in UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, user-controls

Suppose I have a `Window` or `UserControl` with a boatload of named elements. I want to change all  these elements' property values based on a single property of either my view model or a custom DP on the parent (really doesn't matter which, because I can easily bind the DP to the view model property).

Here is a barebones example:

```
<Window x:Class="TriggerFun.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TriggerFun"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Rectangle x:Name="Rect1"
               Grid.Column="0"
               Width="200" Height="200"
               Fill="Red"/>

    <Rectangle x:Name="Rect2"
               Grid.Column="1"
               Width="200" Height="200"
               Fill="Yellow"/>

    <Button Grid.Row="1" 
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Click="Button_Click">
        Swap!
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace TriggerFun
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ViewModel ViewModel => this.DataContext as ViewModel;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ViewModel.AlternativeLayout = !this.ViewModel.AlternativeLayout;
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        bool _alternativeLayout;
        public bool AlternativeLayout
        {
            get => _alternativeLayout;
            set
            {
                _alternativeLayout = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(AlternativeLayout)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to do in this example is swap the columns of the red and yellow `Rectangles` when the user clicks the button. (And yes of course I know I can do this in code-behind. I want to do this in pure XAML).

What would make eminent sense to me is if I could do add this to `Window`:

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AlternativeLayout}" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="Rect1" Property="Grid.Column" Value="1"/>
        <Setter TargetName="Rect2" Property="Grid.Column" Value="0"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

Well that doesn't work because I get a runtime error, `Triggers collection members must be of type EventTrigger.` So all triggers that are children of anything other than a `Style`, `DataTemplate`, or `ControlTemplate` I guess have to be `EventTrigger`s? Fine.

So then I try this:

```
<Window.Style>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AlternativeLayout}" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="Rect1" Property="Grid.Column" Value="1"/>
                <Setter TargetName="Rect2" Property="Grid.Column" Value="0"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Style>
```

That won't even compile: `TargetName property cannot be set on a Style Setter.`

I know I can use `TargetName` in `DataTemplate` or `ControlTemplate` Triggers, but when defining `UserControl`'s and `Window`s of course you usually don't set the `DataTemplate` but rather just set the child content directly.

The only thing I can do that I know works is take each element that I want to be changed and give it its own inline style with triggers, with the final XAML looking incredibly ugly:

```
    <Rectangle x:Name="Rect1"
               Width="200" Height="200"
               Fill="Red">
        <Rectangle.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AlternativeLayout}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="1"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Rectangle.Style>
    </Rectangle>

    <Rectangle x:Name="Rect2"
               Width="200" Height="200"
               Fill="Yellow">
        <Rectangle.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="1"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AlternativeLayout}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Rectangle.Style>
    </Rectangle>
```

Obviously this doesn't scale particularly well.

This is SO easy to do with `ControlTemplate`s and `DataTemplate`s but seems next to impossible when making `UserControl`s. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Generally speaking, binding by custom converters are useful to keep XAML relatively clean. If you don't like them, it is your choice though.

Comment: I'm fine with binding converters but how would they help in my example?

Comment: "Is there something I'm missing?"
You understand everything correctly.
Simplified explanation: `ControlTemplates` and `DataTemplate` are in the same scope as their triggers.
Triggers are part of them, so they "see" the element names.
And the Style of an element with triggers can be anywhere in the view, completely independent of the Content property of this element.
The style "does not know" to which element it will be applied and, accordingly, does not know what is in its Content property.

Comment: @EldHasp yes that makes sense. I guess my question would be, why shouldn't the same rationale hold true for Triggers which are direct children of the `UserControl`? Every FE has a `Triggers` property after all, but it seems to serve an extremely narrow purpose. I guess "that's just how they designed it".

Comment: Add one more layer to the logic of reasoning.
The Template trigger is part of this Template.
Changing a trigger or element is changing the TOTAL Template.
Since this is a single whole, they can be compiled.
If you remove any element that the trigger refers to, then there will be a compilation error.

Comment: But the trigger from Triggers collection and the element from Content property are different entities. They are completely unrelated to each other.
You can separately (for example, on Sharpe) set some kind of trigger, and also change the Content separately.
Therefore, when compiling a trigger, there is no way to be guaranteed to know which names will have which elements.

Comment: And, as you noticed in the comments to the answer below, the names of the elements in the Template and the names of the elements in the Content are declared in XAML by the same constructs, but in fact they are completely different things.
At least the second you can refer to as fields of the class in Code Behind, but the former cannot.
And during compilation, these names are translated into the code in completely different ways.
The same XAML notation is just for the convenience of programmers

Comment: Aha! And of course a `UserControl`'s named elements don't come from a template (unless you do it as suggested below) but live the generated .g.cs codebehind. So of course the compiled `Trigger`s and `Setter`s don't know about them.  But now you have me thinking, you can do a runtime search of the visual tree for a named element. I wonder if I could make my own `UserControlTrigger` that did that. You got me thinking... Thanks!   PS - Aaaaand nevermind. Those wily bastards made all the `TriggerBase` constructor(s) internal. Ghrhgh

Answer (score 1):

You could define a `ControlTemplate` for the window or user control and define the triggers in the template:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:Window23ViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>

    <UserControl>
        <UserControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AlternativeLayout}" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Rect1" Property="Grid.Column" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Rect2" Property="Grid.Column" Value="0"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Rectangle x:Name="Rect1"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           Width="200" Height="200"
                           Fill="Red"/>

                    <Rectangle x:Name="Rect2"
                           Grid.Column="1"
                           Width="200" Height="200"
                           Fill="Yellow"/>

                    <Button Grid.Row="1" 
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Click="Button_Click">
                        Swap!
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </UserControl.Template>
    </UserControl>

</Grid>
```

Comment: I thought about that actually - except using `ContentTemplate`. Potato potahto. One drawback is you lose access to the named elements from the code-behind, but since I want to avoid codebehind it's not a terrible tradeoff.  Good idea!

Answer (score 1):

> [ContentProperty(nameof(Setters))]
> public class ContentTrigger : FrameworkElement

The application of your AttachedProperty can be simplified somewhat.
Let's change the implementation a bit:

```
    [ContentProperty(nameof(Setters))]
    public class ContentTrigger : FrameworkElement
    {
        #region ContentTriggerCollection Triggers dependency property
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TriggersProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                    "ShadowTriggers",
                    typeof(ContentTriggerCollection),
                    typeof(ContentTrigger),
                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                        null,
                        OnTriggersChanged));
        public static ContentTriggerCollection GetTriggers(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            var value = (ContentTriggerCollection)obj.GetValue(TriggersProperty);
            if (value == null)
                SetTriggers(obj, value = new ContentTriggerCollection());
            return value;
        }
        public static void SetTriggers(DependencyObject obj, ContentTriggerCollection value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(TriggersProperty, value);
        }
        private static void OnTriggersChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.OldValue is ContentTriggerCollection oldTriggers)
                oldTriggers.SetApply(null);

            if (args.NewValue is ContentTriggerCollection newTriggers)
                newTriggers.SetApply(obj);
        }
        #endregion

        public BindingBase Binding { get; set; }

        public object Value { get; set; }

        public SetterBaseCollection Setters { get; } = new SetterBaseCollection();

        #region object ActualValue dependency property
        internal static readonly DependencyProperty ActualValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ActualValue",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(ContentTrigger),
            new PropertyMetadata(
                (object)null,
                (obj, args) =>
                {
                    ((ContentTrigger)obj).OnActualValueChanged(args);
                }));
        private void OnActualValueChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (TestIsTriggered(args.NewValue))
                ExecuteTrigger();
            else
                RestoreValues();
        }
        #endregion

        private bool TestIsTriggered(object newValue)
        {
            if (newValue is bool b)
                return b && (this.Value as string == "True" || this.Value as string == "true") ||
                    !b && (this.Value as string == "False" || this.Value as string == "false");
            else
                return object.Equals(this.Value, newValue);
        }

        public void Apply(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            if (!(obj is FrameworkElement fe))
                return;
            _target = fe;
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, DataContextProperty, new Binding
            {
                Source = fe,
                Path = new PropertyPath(DataContextProperty)
            });
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, ActualValueProperty, this.Binding);
        }

        private void ExecuteTrigger()
        {
            if (_target == null || _isTriggered)
                return;
            foreach (var setterBase in this.Setters)
            {
                if (!(setterBase is Setter setter) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(setter.TargetName))
                    continue;

                var targetElem = GetTargetElement(setter.TargetName);
                if (targetElem == null)
                    continue;

                _originalValues[(targetElem, setter.Property)] = targetElem.GetValue(setter.Property);
                targetElem.SetCurrentValue(setter.Property, ResolveSetterValue(setter));
            }
            _isTriggered = true;
        }

        private void RestoreValues()
        {
            if (_target == null || !_isTriggered)
                return;
            foreach (var setterBase in this.Setters)
            {
                if (!(setterBase is Setter setter) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(setter.TargetName))
                    continue;

                var targetElem = GetTargetElement(setter.TargetName);
                if (targetElem == null ||
                    // Value changed some other way since trigger?
                    targetElem.GetValue(setter.Property) != ResolveSetterValue(setter))
                    continue;

                object restoredValue;
                if (_originalValues.TryGetValue((targetElem, setter.Property), out restoredValue))
                {
                    targetElem.SetCurrentValue(setter.Property, restoredValue);
                }
            }
            _isTriggered = false;
        }

        private FrameworkElement GetTargetElement(string name)
        {
            FrameworkElement targetElem;
            if (!_targetElements.TryGetValue(name, out targetElem))
            {
                targetElem = _target.FindName(name) as FrameworkElement;
                if (targetElem != null)
                    _targetElements[name] = targetElem;
            }
            return targetElem;
        }

        private object ResolveSetterValue(Setter setter)
        {
            if (setter.Value is DynamicResourceExtension dr)
                return _target.FindResource(dr.ResourceKey);
            return setter.Value;
        }

        private Dictionary<(FrameworkElement, DependencyProperty), object> _originalValues =
            new Dictionary<(FrameworkElement, DependencyProperty), object>();
        private Dictionary<string, FrameworkElement> _targetElements = new Dictionary<string, FrameworkElement>();
        private bool _isTriggered = false;
        private FrameworkElement _target;
    }
```

```
    public class ContentTriggerCollection : Collection<ContentTrigger>
    {
        public DependencyObject Apply { get; private set; }
        public void SetApply(DependencyObject apply)
        {
            Apply = apply;
            foreach (ContentTrigger trigger in this)
            {
                if (trigger != null)
                    trigger.Apply(apply);
            }
        }

        protected override void ClearItems()
        {
            foreach (ContentTrigger trigger in this)
            {
                if (trigger != null)
                    trigger.Apply(null);
            }

            base.ClearItems();
        }

        protected override void InsertItem(int index, ContentTrigger item)
        {
            base.InsertItem(index, item);
            if (item != null)
                item.Apply(Apply);
        }

        protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
        {
            if (this[index] is ContentTrigger removeTrigger)
                removeTrigger.Apply(null);
            base.RemoveItem(index);
        }

        protected override void SetItem(int index, ContentTrigger item)
        {
            if (this[index] is ContentTrigger removeTrigger)
                removeTrigger.Apply(null);
            base.SetItem(index, item);
            if (item != null)
                item.Apply(Apply);
        }
    }
```

```
<local:ContentTrigger.Triggers>
    
        <local:ContentTrigger Binding="{Binding AlternativeLayout}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Rect1" Property="Grid.Column" Value="1"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Rect1" Property="Rectangle.Fill" Value="Green"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Rect1" Property="Rectangle.Stroke" Value="Purple"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Rect2" Property="Grid.Column" Value="0"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Rect2" Property="Rectangle.Fill" Value="Gray"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Rect2" Property="Rectangle.Stroke" Value="Black"/>
        </local:ContentTrigger>
    
</local:ContentTrigger.Triggers>
```

**The key change is registering the name "ShadowTriggers"**, which is different from the name of the Get and Set methods.
This registration does not allow XAML to refer to the AttachedProperty without going through the getter and setter.

Comment: I like this but lazily constructing the collection in the getter doesn't seem to work. I get a runtime null reference error if I don't include an explicit `ContentTriggerCollection`. I think the problem is when objects are constructed through XAML your `GetXXX` and `SetXXX` don't get called it just uses `GetValue` and `SetValue` with the DP key.

Comment: Did you repeat all my code completely?
The key to understanding the solution is registering the name "ShadowTriggers".
It is this registration that makes XAML always refer to SetValue and GetValue.

Comment: Ahhh very clever. I searched around for "how do you set a default property value for an attached property" and never came across that trick. Thanks!